# JS: assigning document.getElement... doesn't work with var/let (works without)

Tags: javascript, var, let

If I do

```
x = document.getElementsByClassName("something")[0]
```

I get the expected result.

But if I do

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("something")[0]
```

or

```
let x = document.getElementsByClassName("something")[0]
```

I get undefined.

Why is that?

Comment: are you talking about pasting those lines in console?

Comment: I don’t think that’s the issue. May you show us a [mcve]? Preferably a stack snippet?

Comment: I'm guessing you're doing this in the console. The output of the console has some quirks to it, best to do your coding in a proper sandbox or in an actual JS file

Comment: This DOES work - it just doesn't output the value of the variable. You can still use the variable normally.

Comment: Also, don't use standalone names when creating variables - only browser consoles allow this (i.e. use `var x` instead of just `x`).

Comment: Yes, I was doing this in the console.
I think I get it now:
Assigning a value to a global variable returns that value, but with var/let it doesn't, right? Weird.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: doing it with var/let gives you the result of defining a variable (undefined). try `var x=7; x=3`. the first will return `undefined` the second will return the value `3`. the first is the result of declaring a variable, the second is the result of an assignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declaring a variable doesn't return anything (ie, `undefined`), however assigning a variable does return the value.  For example:

```
let x, y
x = y = 7  // this sets both x & y to seven
```

The line above works because `y = 7` returns the value of `y` which is then assigned to `x`. However you can't do anything with a variable declaration:

```
let x = 7
x = let y = 3  // syntax error
```

The point is that declaring a variable does not return a value, which is why you see `undefined` after it in console (also in node REPL), but assignments or other values that do return a value will display that value.

Note that you can do this:

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("something")[0]
x   // this line will return the value of x
```

Answer (score 0):

The `document.getElementsByClassName` will return the array named as `HTMLCollection`

Please have a look in this code,

```
var testElements = document.getElementsByClassName('test');
var testDivs = Array.prototype.filter.call(testElements, function(testElement){
  return testElement.nodeName === 'DIV';
});
```

Also you can check the details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

Comment: Also mention that it’s a “live” collection. Not just a snapshot